# JPA EmbeddedId with @OneToMany - can't make query with JOIN to work

Tags: spring-data-jpa, many-to-many, jpql

We are building an appointment scheduler. We have many guests, and each can visit many events: entities "Guest" and "Event". It's a many to many with intermediate entity, which is called "EventGuestRelation". It has @EmbeddedId with two Integer foreign key columns, that persists fine, and the built-in JPArepository methods behave normally.

The problem is when I query the EventGuestRelation's repository. 
**I can't make the program return me EventGuestRelations that contain a specific Event, or a specific Guest.** Just zero. I'm showing the queries on Event here for brevity.

I've tried

```
@Query("SELECT r.event FROM EventGuestRelation r WHERE r.event= :event")    
public List<EventEntity> getEventIdsForEvent(@Param(value = "event") EventEntity event);
```

and

```
public List<EventGuestRelation> findByEvent(EventEntity event);
```

Both produce SQL:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        evententit1_.id as id1_3_,
    ...
    from
        user_event_guest eventguest0_ 
    inner join
        eventlist evententit1_ 
            on eventguest0_.event_sub=evententit1_.id 
    where
        eventguest0_.event_sub=?
```

The right entity:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class EventEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "event" , cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true) 
    @JsonBackReference 
    private Set<EventGuestRelation> subscriptions = new HashSet<>();
    ...
```

The intermediate entity:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class EventGuestRelation {

    @Embeddable
    public static class EventGuestId implements Serializable {

        @Column(name = "EVENT_ID")
        protected Integer eventId;
        ... 
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    protected EventGuestId id = new EventGuestId();

    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_sub", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private EventEntity event;
    ...
```

Left entity (Guest) omitted.

Repository:

```
public interface EventGuestRepository extends JpaRepository<EventGuestRelation, EventGuestId> {
```

And parts of the test method:

```
private final UserEntity ALYSSA = new UserEntity();
private final EventEntity GUESTING = new EventEntity();
private final EventGuestRelation AGUESTING = new EventGuestRelation();
userRepo.save(ALYSSA); // cascades to intemediate entity, checked;
AGUESTING.subscribe(ALYSSA, GUESTING); //bidirectional relation setter

List<EventEntity> eventsII = eventGuestRepo.getEventIdsForEvent(GUESTING);
        assertEquals(eventsII.size(), 1); // fails
```

**I can solve  the problem this suboptimal way:**

```
   Set<EventGuestRelation> subscriptions = ALYSSA.getSubscriptions();
   Set<EventEntity> events = subscriptions.stream().map(s -> s.getEvent()).collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

but obviously this is not as elegant as querying the database directly.

Any help will be much appreciated. 
P.S. It's the same Alyssa from SICP. 
Some mascots just refuse to pass into obscurity.

Comment: Is there `event_guest_relation` table in your database?

Comment: Yes, of course. My plan of action is to fill the DB with mock data and write the needed query by hand; and then check if the JPA generated queries differ.

Comment: I've made the queries `@Query("SELECT r.userGuest FROM EventGuestRelation r WHERE r.event = :event")    
 public List<UserEntity> getGuestsForEvent (@Param(value = "event") EventEntity event); 
 ` to work by removing  _insertable_ and _updatable_  from the OneToMany mappings in the intermediate entity.  Now what kind of problem I'm introducing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names of the join columns must be equal to the corresponding names of the columns in the embedded primary key. I had missed that. Therefore my intermediate entity had 4 columns in the database instead of 2. That led to the query returning nulls.
After I had made the names equal, the queries worked.

The intermediate entity, corrected, has in the embedded key:
`@Column(name = "GUEST_ID")
protected Integer userGuestId;`

And in the join column:
`@ManyToOne 
@JoinColumn(name = "GUEST_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false) 
private UserEntity guest;`

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with `@Embeddable` entities. Perhaps, you can use something useful in this article of [Spring-Data docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions), but as a backup plan I think you can always rewrite your queries using native SQL.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT e FROM event_guest_relation AS egr JOIN event AS e ON egr.event_id = e.id WHERE egr.event_id = :eventId", nativeQuery = true)
public List<EventEntity> getEventIdsForEvent(@Param(value = "eventId") Integer eventId);
```

and

```
@Query(value = "SELECT egr FROM event AS e JOIN event_guest_relation AS egr ON egr.event_id = e.id WHERE e.id = :eventId", nativeQuery = true)
public List<EventGuestRelation> findByEvent(@Param(value = "eventId") Integer eventId);
```